# C# - Array of Labels that are already on the form?

Tags: c#, arrays, label, controls

I currently have a windows form which has 24 labels that require updating regularly currently I am do it this way.

```
private void UpdateLabels()
    {
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Group 1 Team 1
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        lblGroup1Team1Points.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[0].returnPoints());
        lblGroup1Team1Points.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team1Wins.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[0].returnWins());
        lblGroup1Team1Wins.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team1Draws.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[0].returnDraws());
        lblGroup1Team1Draws.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team1Loses.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[0].returnLoses());
        lblGroup1Team1Loses.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team1GoalDifference.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[0].returnGoalDifference());
        lblGroup1Team1GoalDifference.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team1Played.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[0].returngamesPlayed());
        lblGroup1Team1Played.Refresh();

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Group 1 Team 2
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        lblGroup1Team2Points.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[1].returnPoints());
        lblGroup1Team2Points.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team2Wins.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[1].returnWins());
        lblGroup1Team2Wins.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team2Draws.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[1].returnDraws());
        lblGroup1Team2Draws.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team2Loses.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[1].returnLoses());
        lblGroup1Team2Loses.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team2GoalDifference.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[1].returnGoalDifference());
        lblGroup1Team2GoalDifference.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team2Played.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[1].returngamesPlayed());
        lblGroup1Team2Played.Refresh();

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Group 1 Team 3
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        lblGroup1Team3Points.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[2].returnPoints());
        lblGroup1Team3Points.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team3Wins.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[2].returnWins());
        lblGroup1Team3Wins.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team3Draws.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[2].returnDraws());
        lblGroup1Team3Draws.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team3Loses.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[2].returnLoses());
        lblGroup1Team3Loses.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team3GoalDifference.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[2].returnGoalDifference());
        lblGroup1Team3GoalDifference.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team3Played.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[2].returngamesPlayed());
        lblGroup1Team3Played.Refresh();

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Group 1 Team 4
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        lblGroup1Team4Points.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[3].returnPoints());
        lblGroup1Team4Points.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team4Wins.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[3].returnWins());
        lblGroup1Team4Wins.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team4Draws.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[3].returnDraws());
        lblGroup1Team4Draws.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team4Loses.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[3].returnLoses());
        lblGroup1Team4Loses.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team4GoalDifference.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[3].returnGoalDifference());
        lblGroup1Team4GoalDifference.Refresh();
        lblGroup1Team4Played.Text = Convert.ToString(theTeams[3].returngamesPlayed());
        lblGroup1Team4Played.Refresh();
    }
```

This works great, don't get me wrong but its a rather lengthy process when it comes to updating them when it could be done in some sort of loop - So what I'm asking basically is: Is there anyway to add an existing label to an array of labels so that I can update and refresh these labels just by accessing its element in that label array? My thoughts where it would be as easy as this

```
Label[,] group1Labels = new Label[5,7];
private void CreateLabelArray
    {
        group1Labels[0,0] = lblGroup1Team1Points;
    }
```

However I am mistaken as group1Labels gives me the error "A get or set accessor expected" What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Hm there is something else wrong with your code, because what you posted should work

Comment: Why not use a list of labels? List<Label> or a dictionary where you could use a unique identifier as the key Dictionary<string,Label>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how pretty or fast this is but you could try something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theTeams.Length; i++)
{
    foreach(Control ctr in this.Controls)
    {
        if (ctr.Name == "lblGroup1Team" + (i + 1) + "Points")
        {
            ((Label)ctr).Text = theTeams[i].returnPoints();
            ((Label)ctr).Refresh();
        }
        //other ifs for each label
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this to make list

```
foreach (Control c in group1.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Label)
            {
                string name = c.Name;
                // add your code to add in list or array
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the labels using this.
You could maybe call this in your form constructor

```
var labels = GetType()
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(Label))
    .Select(x => (Label)x.GetValue(this))
    .ToArray();
```